# glGenerateMipmaps Access violation error

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I am using Glew to load gl functions and extentions. when I use glGenerateMipmap in the code, it compiles without any error. However when I run the code, I get this error :

> Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

What does it mean ? My card doesn't support that extention or a driver issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` ?

I'd have commented but it seems I can't yet.

Comment: where should I put that line ?